# Making AuraDocs public for an org

Tags: lightning-community, aura-doc

The documentation for an org is available at the following url including those for custom lightning components.

`https://<my-domain>.my.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app`

Is there a way so that i can render the org documentation in a custom lightning component so that i can add the lightning component in a public page in a lightning community.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't make it public. An attempt to access it will result in the following error:

> Error: Login is required to access this URL.
>
> Please email us if you need to get in touch.

This is purely an authenticated experience, as mentioned in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_lc_library.htm).

Comment: Is there a way to export the componentReference somehow

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, there are various ways to do it:

1) **Iframe**: Create a component with Iframe point to your communityURL + `/auradocs/reference.app`

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <h1>Here are auradocs</h1>
     <iframe src="https://mycommunity.salesforce.com/customercommunity/auradocs/reference.app" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</aura:component>
```

2) **Directly Navigate to URL** : Using force:navigateToUrl

```
gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": "https://mycommunity.salesforce.com/customercommunity/auradocs/reference.app"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation

Comment: If i redirect to `communityURL + /auradocs/reference.app` , i get the `Page not available` error

Comment: I was able to do that, can you post community home page url? If your community url end with /s, you have to remove /s and then append the `/auradocs/reference.app`

Comment: i was using `componentReference/suite.app`

Comment: No idea about suite.app,

Comment: @PranayJaiswal suite is the newer docs feature, mentioned in [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_lc_library.htm).